# How to set linux kernel module name from within module code?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

Everyone knows how to set a module name from the Makefile, specifying it in obj-m.

But is it possible to set the module name inside the module source itself?

(not from code.. that can be done very simply) I mean this:

I know there is no macro to set the name but maybe defining something would do.

Or some mangling using objcopy perhaps.

Comment: I didn't ask this. Read again the question.

Comment: OK, now I see - you want to set the module name like the module's licence or author (macros `MODULE_LICENCE`, `MODULE_AUTHOR` or so). I know no way for doing so. And I doubt it exists: a module's filename is determined from the Makefile, not from the module's source files. And the module's filename should reflect the module's name - inconsistency between them would discourage a user of your module a lot. So it is Makefile which should define the module's name, not a source file.

Comment: so, in other words, you don't know :D but thatnks for taking the time to read and understand the question ;)